# Programmatically disassemble CIL

Tags: c#, .net, f#, metaprogramming

I can compile instructions to bytecode and even execute them easily but the only function I have found to extract CIL is `GetILAsByteArray` and, as the name implies, it just returns bytes and not CIL instructions.

So how do you programmatically disassemble CIL on .NET?

Note that I don't want the result in human-readable form. I want to write metaprograms to manipulate the CIL generated from other programs.

Comment: As @JohnPalmer suggests in his answer, [Mono.Cecil](http://www.mono-project.com/Cecil) is a good option for this. [Here](http://plaureano.blogspot.com/2011/05/introduction-to-il-rewriting-with-cecil.html) is a good blog discussing IL rewriting that might be helpful.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can get reasonably far just using the byte array from `GetILAsByteArray` method, but you'll need to write parsing of the bytes yourself (if you don't want to rely on 3rd party library).

The structure of the array is that there is one or two bytes identifying the instruction followed by operands for the instruction (which is either nothing, some 4 byte token or a 8 byte number).

To get the codes, you can look at the `OpCodes` structure ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.aspx)) from `System.Reflection.Emit`. If you enumerate over all the fields, you can quite easily build a lookup table for reading of the bytes:

```
// Iterate over all byte codes to build lookup table
for fld in typeof<OpCodes>.GetFields() do
  let code = fld.GetValue(null) :?> OpCode
  printfn "%A (%d + %A)" code.Name code.Size code.OperandType
```

The `code.Value` property gives you eithre `byte` or `int16` value of the code. The `code.Size` property tells you whether this is 1 or 2 byte code and `OperandType` property specifies what arguments follow the code (the number of bytes and the meaning is [explained on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.operandtype.aspx)). I don't remember how exactly you need to process things like tokens that refer to i.e. `MethodInfo`, but I guess you'll be able to figure that out!

Answer (score 9):

The Mono Cecil library - http://www.mono-project.com/Cecil should do what you need, I know that it is used in at least one .Net profiler

Comment: You might want to look at this blog posting http://plaureano.blogspot.com/2011/05/introduction-to-il-rewriting-with-cecil.html for a bit more information on using Cecil to accomplish what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 5):

One interesting alternative to using Cecil would be to resurrect the [AbsIL](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/tree/master/src/absil) project. Cecil  well written and well used, but it probably isn't how you'd approach the problem if you were writing it in F#. AbsIL was a project started at the same time as F# to allow OCaml and F# to read and write IL, it's since been over taken as by the F# project and is now just the back end for the F# compiler. However the code to both read and write IL is still there and could in theory be separated from the F# compiler and made into usable library in it's own right. Separating the AbsIL code from the rest of the F# compiler is not completely trivial, but should be possible if you have a bit of spare time and a certain amount of determination. If you're feeling really brave you might also want to look at cross compiling it to OCaml.

Answer (score 2):

I did some IL manipulation with [Mono Cecil](http://www.mono-project.com/Cecil) project. It's quite easy API.